# HTTP to HTTPS Server Port

Tags: java, spring-boot, port, keystore

I'm really at my wits end. I've been working on this project trying to get the keystore path correct so I can generate a selfsigned certificate in my program files instead of in the Java/bin, finally got that fixed. I generated the PKCS12 and certificate, I got it all working on the required port 8443.
Then I had trouble converting it from HTTP to a secure HTTPS. That was a royal pain in the @! I thought I finally figured it all out and I finally have a secure port with no security warning on Chrome EXCEPT it only works on the default port 8080 and not 8443.
If I try to force it to use port 8443 the program shuts down after a second saying there was an error.
I'm supposed to input https://localhost:8443/hash and have a secure connection.
What am I doing wrong?
I still have more of this project to work on and I'm just worn out already.

If I use the provided layout:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
```

Port 8443 will work however it won't be secure.
If I use this layout:

```
server:
    ssl:
        key-store:classpath:keystore.p12
        key-store-password: password
        key-store-type: pkcs12
        key-store-alias: tomcat
        key-password: password
    port=8443
```

Then it will finally have a secure connection, however, only on the default port 8080

Comment: "saying there was an error" -- what error?

Comment: It says that it started SslServerAppplication but then stops saying there was an error parsing HTTP request header because invalid character found in method name.

Comment: Please add the full text of the error message and any stack trace to your question.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I think it's on Chromes end or something. If I type in localhost:8443/hash it pops up without error. If I type in https://localhost:8443/hash then the error pops up: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens